# How can I reproduce this graph of theorems?

Tags: diagrams, graphs

I saw this really nice summary of all the theorems in a chapter, and there were 5 theorems arranged in a pentagon shape. They had the implication arrows ([image: => <=>]) showing how they related to each other.

How can I reproduce this?
[image: A connected graph of theorems (that looks like a house)]

Here is what I have currently:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (ftli) {FTLI};
    \node (pi) [below left of=ftli] {Path Independent};
    \node (cons) [below right of=ftli] {Conservative};
    \node[draw,dotted] (0) [below of=pi] {Zero};
    \node[draw,dotted] (sym) [below of=cons] {Symmetric};
    
    \draw[double,<-] (ftli) -- (pi);
    \draw[double,<-] (ftli) -- (cons);
    \draw[double,->] (pi) -- (cons);
    \draw[double,<->] (pi) -- (0);
    \draw[double,<-] (0) -- (sym);
    \draw[double,->] (cons) -- (sym);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I'm not quite sure how I should add the labels to the implications, and I also am not sure how to space this out further.

Also, I can't add equations, when I do

```tex
\begin{equation}
5x + 3
\end{equation}
```

It says `` You can't use `\eqno' in restricted horizontal mode. ``

Comment: Have a look at tikz

Comment: hi, thanks but how do I get the implication arrows?

Comment: `\draw[double,<->] (a) -- (b);`

Comment: sorry for so many questions, but how can I embed the equations into the box?

Comment: That's the problem with asking such a broad question. Have a look at the tikz user guide, it contains a lot of examples. Then show in your question how far you got yourself and ask specific questions of whatever remains to be done.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me! I've updated the question with my attempt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- you have better control over the spacing with the `positioning` library
- you can use `\draw (...) -- (...) node[midway] {text};` to add labels to your arrows
- you can use equations in nodes if you set a width for the node

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (ftli) {FTLI};
    \node[text width=4cm,align=center,draw] (pi) [below left= 3cm of ftli] {Path Independent
    \[
    a+b=c
    \]
    test
    };
    
    \draw[double,<-] (ftli) -- (pi) node[midway,above] {test};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```